# Which python version for standalone script with Qgis module

Tags: pyqgis, installation, standalone

I'm writing a standalone python script, and I need to use Qgis module.
For information i'm working on a Mac and I already have Qgis 2.18 installed.
So in list of module importation, I wrote this :

```
import qgis
```

But when I run my script, it returns me :

```
No module named 'qgis'
```

I search where it comes from, and apparently, it's because I have many python versions installed. And I dont use the one who is connected to Qgis.

I check my python install with this command `which -a python python3`and it returns :

```
/opt/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

According to `python --version` I'm using Python 3.4.7

Somebody can help me to use the good one ?

Comment: `Qgis 2.18 installed`: how did you install Qgis, KyngChaos, Homebrew, ?

Comment: I used KyngChaos way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS 2.18 uses python 2.7.

QGIS 3 will use python 3.

Comment: I used `python --version` to know my current version. It is Python 3.4.7. So i have to change current version to 2.7 and it will be ok ? How can I do that ?